# wxWidgets in c++ on windows

Tags: c++, multithreading, wxwidgets

I was reading this particular code snippet:-

```
  class WXDLLIMPEXP_CORE wxCommandEvent : public wxEvent, public wxEventBasicPayloadMixin
```

this is defined in event.h header file , i didn't understand "WXDLLIMPEXP_CORE".

Thanks

Comment: wxWidgets uses a lot of macros like that. You might be able to know more by checking where the macro is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have a look at [where it is defined](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/browser/wxWidgets/trunk/include/wx/dlimpexp.h) we see

```
#ifdef WXMAKINGDLL_CORE
#    define WXDLLIMPEXP_CORE WXEXPORT
#    define WXDLLIMPEXP_DATA_CORE(type) WXEXPORT type
#    if defined(HAVE_VISIBILITY)
#        define WXDLLIMPEXP_INLINE_CORE WXEXPORT
#    else
#        define WXDLLIMPEXP_INLINE_CORE
#    endif
#elif defined(WXUSINGDLL)
#    define WXDLLIMPEXP_CORE WXIMPORT
#    define WXDLLIMPEXP_DATA_CORE(type) WXIMPORT type
#    if defined(HAVE_VISIBILITY)
#        define WXDLLIMPEXP_INLINE_CORE WXIMPORT
#    else
#        define WXDLLIMPEXP_INLINE_CORE
#    endif
#else /* not making nor using DLL */
#    define WXDLLIMPEXP_CORE
#    define WXDLLIMPEXP_DATA_CORE(type) type
#    define WXDLLIMPEXP_INLINE_CORE
#endif
```

The comments elsewhere in the file are pretty explanatory as to what is happening, but a brief summary is that there are three cases, we are making a DLL, using a DLL or not using one at all. The last case is the simplest, if we are not using DLLs at all then they are defined away to nothing. If we are making a DLL then it marks the class as exported, and if we are using a DLL then it marks the class as imported.

Comment: I got some part of it , in this i consider the class as to be exported(wxCommandEvent),asWXDLLIMPEXP_CORE is not making any use of Dll how would that matters if a class is exported or imported depending upon if the DLL's are used to create DLL's